# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gifsicle': 'gifsicle' in Google Colab

Tags: python, optimization, pip, google-colaboratory, gifsicle

I'm trying to optimize a gif using pygifsicle's optimize function, working in the Colab environment. I've used `!pip install pygifscile` which successfully installs pygifsicle-1.0.1. However whether I use `import pygifsicle` or `from pygifsicle import optimize` I still get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gifsicle': 'gifsicle'
```

I understand that gifsicle is a prerequesite for pygifsicle, how can I install it in Colab?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

Realizing that Colab runs Ubuntu command, I simply ran `!sudo apt-get install gifsicle` after my cell: `from pygifsicle import optimize`, and can now call the optimize function with no issues!